# Is the X-Matched-Path for my public image path cached in Next.js when using caching?

Tags: caching, next.js, vercel

I've structured my site using Next.js and configured caching as follows:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins')
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')
const bundleAnalyzer = withBundleAnalyzer({
  compress: true,
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
  openAnalyzer: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
})

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: false,
  swcMinify: true,
  images: {
    formats: ['image/avif', 'image/webp'],
    domains: ['github.com', 'user-images.githubusercontent.com'],
  },
  compiler: {
    styledComponents: true,
    removeConsole: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  },
  webpack: config => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    })
    config.plugins.push(new CompressionPlugin())
    return config
  },
}
module.exports = withPlugins([bundleAnalyzer], nextConfig)
```

Additionally, my vercel.json is configured as follows:

```
{
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/static/fonts/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "public,s-maxage=31536000, immutable"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "source": "/manifest.json", 
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "public, max-age=0, s-maxage=86400"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "source": "/favicon.ico",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "public, max-age=0, s-maxage=86400"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "source": "/static/images/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "public, max-age=0, s-maxage=86400"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, when inspecting the site, it seems cached, but I'm unsure if it's properly cached.

[My Response Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNYQL.png)

Questions:

1. For X-Vercel-Cache: HIT, should X-Matched-Path be /.next/cache or can it still be cached as shown above with the public/static image path?
2. With the configuration public, max-age: 0, s-maxage: 86400, does Vercel Edge Caching retrieve the images from the server for the specified caching time, or does it fetch them from Vercel Edge Cache? Why does a MISS occur after a long period, even if I visit the site again after an hour?
   If there's something incorrect in my approach or if I'm missing a step, I'd appreciate guidance on resolving this!

I'm Not Sure About That